# VBA - Subscript Out of Range Error on MOD command

Tags: excel, vba

I am still a novice VBA user.  I can't seem to get my head around why this bit of script is not working.  I get a

> 'Subscript Out of Range' error

on the second line in the `If` statement of the below:

```
Sub ScreenUpdate()

Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If Cells(i, 17).Value = Cells(i - 1, 17).Value Then
                Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = ";;;"
                Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = ";;;"
                Cells(i, 15).NumberFormat = ";;;"
                Cells(i, 16).NumberFormat = ";;;"
            Else
                Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "0"
                Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "0"
                Cells(i, 15).NumberFormat = "0"
                Cells(i, 16).NumberFormat = "0"
            End If
        Next i

        For j = 2 To LastRow
            If Cells(j, 17).Value Mod 2 = 1 Then
                Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 16)).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(221, 235, 247)
            Else
                Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 16)).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            End If
        Next j

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Many thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Error on which line specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed up [`Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color), which you would use the `RGB` function with,  and [`ColorIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.colorindex).

The `RGB` function returns a `Long` whole number corresponding to the color value. Specifically in this case,

- `RGB(221, 235, 247)` returns *16,247,773*
- `RGB(255, 255, 255)` returns *16,777,215*

Both of these are outside the very narrow range of possible values for a color *index* in the current color palette, hence the `subscript out of range`.

Change each instance of `ColorIndex` to `Color`.